# Prove that the expression $2x_1^2 + 2x_1x_2 + x_2^2$ is positive

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $S = 2x_1^2 + 2x_1x_2 + x_2^2$.

$x_1$ and $x_2$ are not simultaneously zero. $|x_1| + |x_2| > 0$. How can I prove that $S > 0$.

Case 1:

$x_1 = 0$ and $x_2 \neq 0$. In this case $S > 0$ for sure.

Case 2:

$x_1 \neq 0$ and $x_2 \neq 0$ and $x_1 \ge x_2$.

If both $x_1$ and $x_2$ of same sign then $S>0$.

If both $x_1$ and $x_2$ of different sign then how to proceed?

Comment: You can rewrite it as:$$x_1^2+(x_1+x_2)^2$$ and the square of a real is always nonnegative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$S = x_1^2 + (x_1^2 + 2x_1 x_2 + x_2^2) = x_1^2 + (x_1 + x_2)^2.$$